# next pointer element in linked list structure

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

In the code

```
struct link *node
{
 int data;
 struct link *next;
};
```

Is next element pointer to pointer? 
And what does `node=node->next` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following isn't valid C (it won't compile):

```
struct link *node
{
  int data;
  struct link *next;
};
```

You probably want:

```
struct link
{
  int data;
  struct link *next;
} * node;
```

---

> Is next element pointer to pointer[?]

No, (if instantiated) `next` is a pointer to `struct link`.

---

> what does `node=node->next` do?

It assigns to `node` where `node->next` would point to.

Answer (score 0):

In your struct, the instance field `next` stores a pointer to the next link.

This line

```
currNode = currNode->next;
```

...makes the pointer `currNode` point to the node that follows the node that `currNode` previously pointed to.

The operator `->` is the same as dot syntax but for pointers.

However, in the code you provided `node->next` wouldn't do anything because you do not have a variable named "node".

Also, the definition of you struct won't compile.  It should be `struct link`, not `struct link *node`.

Comment: There are some good websites around that explain linked lists, This one seemed at a cursory look to be ok  http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson15.html

Comment: @AngusConnell It was my understanding that the question was more about C and pointers than about linked lists.  I guess we'll see what the OP does.